# Пример Rest API на java - Server Error 500

Tags: java, oracle, rest, http-status-code-500

При выполнении [примера](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_grizzly_jersey/jersey-grizzly-json-service.html#section6) с Rest API c сайта Oracle выпадает ошибка сервера 500. Лог показывает:`WARNING: The (sub)resource method add in NoteService contains empty path annotation.` Как я понимаю, проблема в самом методе `getAll()`,не получается у него вывести то, что надо. Вероятно не тот формат. Не могу понять, как поправить это место.

Вот сам код:

Note.java

```
public class Note {
    private final UUID id;
    private final String title;

    private Note(NoteBuilder builder){
        this.id = builder.id;
        this.title = builder.title;
    }

    public Note(){
        Note not = new Note.NoteBuilder().id().build();
        this.id = not.getId();
        this.title = not.getTitle();
    }

    public Note(UUID id, String title) {
        Note not = new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                .title(title)
                .build();

        this.id = not.getId();
        this.title = not.getTitle();
    }

    public UUID getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "ID: " + id
                + " Title: " + title;
    }

    public static class NoteBuilder{
        private UUID id;
        private String title = "";

        public NoteBuilder id(){
            this.id =  UUID.randomUUID();
            return this;
        }

        public NoteBuilder title(String title){
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Note build(){
            return new Note(this);
        }
    }
}
```

NoteList.java

```
public class NoteList {
    private static final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> nList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    static {
        nList.add(
                new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                        .title("1 заметка")
                        .build()
        );

        nList.add(
                new Note.NoteBuilder().id()
                        .title("2 заметка")
                        .build()
        );
    }
    private NoteList() {
    }

    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> getInstance(){
            return nList;
        }
}
```

NoteService.java

```
@Path("/notes")
public class NoteService {

    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Note> nList = NoteList.getInstance();

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Note[] getAll(){
        return nList.toArray(new Note[0]);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The (sub)resource method add in NoteService contains empty path
>   annotation.

переводится как

> Метод `add` в `NoteService` содержит пустую аннотацию `path`.

Вы действительно привели код класса `NoteService` полностью?

Comment: у оракла в его реализации сервиса есть работа с POST-запросом. Код такой:
`@POST
  @Path("/add")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response addCustomer(Customer customer){
    cList.add(customer);
    return Response.status(201).build();
  }`
Здесь и встречается `add`.

Но я для начала хотел просто вывести созданный массив в виде JSON, а уже потом изучить другие виды запросов. Или в обязательном порядке необходимо выводить все запросы, пусть даже с методами, которые будут возвращать `null`?

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать тот код, который не используете в данный момент.

Comment: а его и нет, код своего сервиса я привёл полностью

Comment: Тогда вам остаётся выяснить, каким чудесным образом Java догадывается, что он там был.

Comment: Но ведь по сути, у оракла `add` это же не метод, а путь в аннотации. а вообще в целом, во всём проекте метод `add` есть. Это добавление объектов в список. Встречается он в приведённом мной классе `NoteList.java`

Comment: В ошибке чётко написано "Метод add класса NoteService".

Comment: Но ведь метода `add` нет в этом классе. Есть ещё какие-то файлы, которые создаёт система, где на него может что-то ссылаться?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, как и ожидалось в самом методе `getAll()`. Код поправил таким образом:

```
@GET
@Path("/all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getAll(){
    return nList.toString();
}
```

Браузер вывел то, что и требовалось.

> [ID: 313695e0-72a5-4aab-9047-fbec516dab4f Title: 1 заметка, ID:
>   9e4b9d09-347b-439c-aecf-b259b086f987 Title: 2 заметка]

Но в логах сервера ошибка метод `add` так и осталась. Сия тайна осталась покрыта мраком...